# How to get a ZAV

Tags: germany, indian-citizens

I am an IT professional with 13.5 years of experience in Infrastructure domain. I am interested in relocating to Germany and been contacted by one of the firms in India who can help me get a job there,however they need a ZAV certificate first and ask me to register for it online.
Can you please help me how can I get the ZAV certificate by myself.Wat is the process.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have recently applied to equivalence from ZAB.

Here are the steps.

Apply for the Anabin [equivalence certificate for bachelors and above degrees] on this [link](https://anabin.kmk.org/antragsformular.html?L=1) at KMK site.

1. The required docs for this can be found here.
2. This is THE MOST IMPORTANT document and is needed in most of the cases because even if you find your university is listed [here](https://anabin.kmk.org/no_cache/filter/institutionen.html), your exact degree name might not be. In cases both are listed, this step may be skipped for the visa interview but you’ll still need it for applying for the blue card later so better apply for it asap.
3. Tick the blue card option while filling the form for applying for this. This way you’ll receive the certificate within a week of payment submission.
4. Pay the fee of 200 Euros (paid by the employer in work visa cases)

Comment: Welcome, samar! Can you clarify where the required docs can be found? At the first link? In (b), what is the most important document? Is it the degree equivalence document?

Comment: for work visa in Germany, the equivalence of your foreign degree is considered an important document, I have applied work visa from Pakistan and now waiting for ZAB for the Statement of Comparability document as German Embassy has asked for it even though I have the contract of employment as well.

Comment: For a standard work visa (not Blue card)  from India, do we still need a recognized degree as per anabin?